# Trying to implement Gouraud shading, not exactly what I am looking for

Tags: c++, graphics

[image]

these are the results

way far from what it is supposed to be.

I do calculate the color at each vertex first and sent it to linear interpolation to get the color

```
scene.light.Set_Normal(glm::normalize(normalprojection*glm::vec4(scene.GetModel(j).GetNormal(scene.GetModel(j).GetFace(i).GetVertexIndex(0) - 1),1.0f)));

colorp1=scene.light.Compute_Color(scene.GetModel(j), i, scene.GetActiveCamera().eye, temp1);

scene.light.Set_Normal(glm::normalize(normalprojection*glm::vec4(scene.GetModel(j).GetNormal(scene.GetModel(j).GetFace(i).GetVertexIndex(1) - 1),1.0f)));

colorp2=scene.light.Compute_Color(scene.GetModel(j), i, scene.GetActiveCamera().eye, temp2);
            
            scene.light.Set_Normal(glm::normalize(normalprojection*glm::vec4(scene.GetModel(j).GetNormal(scene.GetModel(j).GetFace(i).GetVertexIndex(2) - 1),1.0f)));

colorp3=scene.light.Compute_Color(scene.GetModel(j), i, scene.GetActiveCamera().eye, temp3);
```

temp1, temp2, temp3, are the vertices after applying all transformations

```
glm::vec3 Renderer::Gouraud_shading(glm::vec3 p1,glm::vec3 p2,glm::vec3 p3,glm::vec3 colorp1,glm::vec3 colorp2,glm::vec3 colorp3,glm::vec3 point)
{
    float A_1 = area(p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y, point.x, point.y);
    float A_2 = area(p1.x, p1.y, p3.x, p3.y, point.x, point.y);
    float A_3 = area(p2.x, p2.y, p1.x, p1.y, point.x, point.y);
    float A = A_1 + A_2 + A_3;
    glm::vec3 temp=glm::vec3(A_1/A,A_2/A,A_3/A);
    return (colorp1*temp.x,colorp2*temp.y,colorp3*temp.z);
    
}
```

anyone?

Comment: The vertex color should be common for all the triangles -- and that may need to be calculated by averaging the normals of each plane sharing the vertex and applying a Lambertian model of reflection to the normal.

Comment: You tell us only that your results are "way far from what it is supposed to be", but it's not clear what you expected. I bet you'll get better participation on your question if you ask something more specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.